# Force landscape mode only for tablet/mobile, not desktop

Tags: jquery, css

I have to rotate the content on tablet and mobile device but not on desktop.

I tried

- `rorate(90deg)` -> Not working 'cause it rotate even on desktop
- `@media screen and (orientation:lanscape)` -> Not working 'cause it rotate even on desktop

So if you have an idea with CSS or JS/jQuery it would be very good :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes on media queries, but you should combine media features. `orientation: landscape` by itself is not enough. Try something like:

`@media (max-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ...` }

More on media queries from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) (a must read).

Comment: It change the content on desktop too

Comment: The code I provided is only a sample and does not mean to work. What I am saying is that you should read more on media queries to understand how the work.

Comment: You’d probably rather want to use a max-width here, so that those styles are only applied on small enough screens - right now, it is the opposite.

Comment: I think media queries aren't the solution, for the same reason that I mentionned. I'll take a look for a Js plugin